# Unable to install Django with pipenv because of pytz package failure

Tags: python, django, pipenv

This has caused problems for me when developing with django, the simplest case to reproduce this error follows.

I'm using Anaconda 4.6.4 running Python 3.6.5, pip version 19.0.3, and pipenv version 2018.11.26. I've updated all the packages, even tried to use previous versions of several packages.

When I use:

```
pipenv shell
```

I get a new virtual environment, then I try:

```
pipenv install django
```

I then get the following error message:

```
Installing django…
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (85c883)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (85c883)…
An error occurred while installing pytz==2018.9 --hash=                                                                       ! Will try again.
  ================================ 2/2 - 00:00:01
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1992, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       skip_lock=skip_lock,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Usage: pip [options]', '', 'Invalid requirement: pytz==2018.9 --hash=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'pip: error: Arguments to --hash must be a hash name followed by a value, like --hash=sha256:abcde...']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
     ================================ 0/1 - 00:00:00
```

This occurs when I'm using command line, power shell, pycharm, atom editor. I've searched for similar errors online all over the place but can't find anything relevant to this. I tried looking at the pipenv source code for the batch_install and _clean_procs functions among others in the stack trace, but couldn't figure out why it's failing.

Comment: Haven't seen this before. I know it is not a direct solution for this case buy, have you tried adding django in you Pipfile? for example, `django = "==2.*"`

Comment: I tried different versions of django as recommended, it still fails. Not sure if this is a bug with pipenv, django, or pytz and/or if I should report as a bug.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the hash. The next thing I'll try is to delete `Pipenv.lock` and start again

Comment: I suppose that problem is `anaconda`. Can you try to install another python distribution along `anaconda` and run `pipenv` with "normal" python.

Comment: I tried to delete and clear the Pipenv.lock, it still does the same. I've also tried to install under python 3.6 "normal python". So far, the only way I could get this to work is to `pipenv install` a previous version of pytz then it works fine. I believe its some sort of interaction with my current system set up somewhere and the hash for pytz.